# Trouble with py3270 & wc3270 on Windows Server

Tags: python, mainframe, terminal-emulator, 3270

I'm migrating from a linux env to windows.

one of my scripts utilizes py3270 via c3270 to automate a terminal.

I have installed the wc3270 setup found here: http://x3270.bgp.nu/WindowsInstall.html

successfully:
    pip install py3270

I'm trying this test script just to get things working:

```
from py3270 import *
import sys, os

host = "tn3270.testing.net"
e = Emulator(visible=True)
e.connect(host)
e.wait_for_field()
```

i get the error:

"Windows can not find wc3270, make sure you typed the name correctly"

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to get the wc3270 install to be recognized by windows?

Answer (score 2):

Add the location of "wc3270" downloaded from internet to PATH variable. I added that directory by "My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that wc3270 is in your path variable. Py3270 0.20 requires wc3270 in path.

Answer (score 0):

Move the wc3270 directory to the C: drive and your path should be something like this C:\wc3270 in the PATH. It worked for me.